Adams Fourth-Order Predictor-Corrector in MATLAB
I have attempted to implement the algorithm given in my 'Numerical Analysis' textbook (Burden and Faire, 9th edition, page 311.)
I am having trouble with the array index. Arrays are used to store approximated values. The Runge-Kutta computations for three starting values (up to Step 5) seems to work fine. After that, the approximation is imprecise. I would appreciate some guidance as to fixing what I have done wrong.
f= @(t,y) y-t^2+1;
a=0;b=2;
N=10; alpha=0.5;
%Step 1
h=(b-a)/N;
t0=a;w0=alpha;
fprintf("t0,w0= %d,%d\n",t0,w0);
%Step 2: for i=1,2,3 do Steps 3-5: Runge Kutta Method computation of
t_values(4)=0;w_values(4)=0;
t_values(1)=t0;w_values(1)=w0;
for i=1+1:1:3+1
    %Step 3
    k1= h*f(t_values(i-1),w_values(i-1));
    k2= h*f(t_values(i-1)+h/2, w_values(i-1)+k1/2);
    k3= h*f(t_values(i-1)+h/2, w_values(i-1)+k2/2);
    k4= h*f(t_values(i-1)+h, w_values(i-1)+k3);
    %Step 4
    w_values(i)= w_values(i-1)+ (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
    t_values(i)= a+ (i-1)*h;
    %Step 5
    fprintf("t_i,w_i= %d,%d\n",t_values(i),w_values(i));
end

%Step 6: for i=4..N do Steps 7-10
for i=4+1:1:N+1
    %Step 7
    t= a+(i-1)*h;
    w= w_values(4)+h*(55*f(t_values(4),w_values(4)) -59*f(t_values(3),w_values(3)) +37*f(t_values(2),w_values(2)) -9*f(t_values(1),w_values(1)))/24;
    w= w_values(4)+h*(9*f(t,w) +19*f(t_values(4),w_values(4)) -5*f(t_values(3),w_values(3)) +f(t_values(2),w_values(2)))/24;
    %Step 8
    fprintf("t,w= %d,%d\n",t,w);
%Step 9
    for j=0+1:1:2+1
        t_values(j)=t_values(j+1);
        w_values(j)=w_values(j+1);
        %Step 10
        t_values(4)=t;
        w_values(4)=w;
    end
end


Someone else helped me and pointed out that Step 10 was wrongly put in the for-loop. Here's the fixed code:
f= @(t,y) y-t^2+1;
a=0;b=2;
N=10; alpha=0.5;
%Step 1
h=(b-a)/N;
t0=a;w0=alpha;
fprintf("t0,w0= %d,%d\n",t0,w0);
%Step 2: for i=1,2,3 do Steps 3-5: Runge Kutta Method computation of
t_values(4)=0;w_values(4)=0;
t_values(1)=t0;w_values(1)=w0;
for i=1+1:1:3+1
    %Step 3
    k1= h*f(t_values(i-1),w_values(i-1));
    k2= h*f(t_values(i-1)+h/2, w_values(i-1)+k1/2);
    k3= h*f(t_values(i-1)+h/2, w_values(i-1)+k2/2);
    k4= h*f(t_values(i-1)+h, w_values(i-1)+k3);
    %Step 4
    w_values(i)= w_values(i-1)+ (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
    t_values(i)= a+ (i-1)*h;
    %Step 5
    fprintf("t_i,w_i= %d,%d\n",t_values(i),w_values(i));
end

%Step 6: for i=4..N do Steps 7-10
fprintf("start step 6\n");
for i=4+1:1:N+1
    %Step 7
    t= a+(i-1)*h;
    w= w_values(4)+h*(55*f(t_values(4),w_values(4)) -59*f(t_values(3),w_values(3)) +37*f(t_values(2),w_values(2)) -9*f(t_values(1),w_values(1)))/24;
    w= w_values(4)+h*(9*f(t,w) +19*f(t_values(4),w_values(4)) -5*f(t_values(3),w_values(3)) +f(t_values(2),w_values(2)))/24;
    %Step 8
    fprintf("t,w= %d,%d\n",t,w);
%Step 9
    for j=0+1:1:2+1
        t_values(j)=t_values(j+1);
        w_values(j)=w_values(j+1);
    end
    %Step 10
        t_values(4)=t;
        w_values(4)=w;
end

